# SAP GUIXT - Pass Variable and run script

Tags: vbscript, sap-erp, sap-gui

I would like to create an "input field" in SAP that uses the passed value within a vb script. To give a specific example, I would like to open `FBL5N`, pass an invoice into a field and view the invoice in `VF03`. The script to do that is ready and works for a hardcoded value of invoice or thru VBA.

Here is the GUI script part

```
inputfield (2,35)  "inv" (2,45) size=10 name="V_inv"
pushbutton (toolbar)  "print_inv" process="InvoiceScript.txt"
using MYINV = "V_inv"
```

Now, I don't know what to do for the inputscript part. I would like your assistance in this matter. Here is my first attempt:

```
Screen SAPLSLVC.0500
ApplyGuiScript template="VF03INV.vbs"
Enter
```

Thank you for your help and let me know if you need any precision.
Here are my sources of inspiration to get the above code :
http://www.synactive.com/tutor_e/lessonia03.html
http://www.synactive.com/docu_e/docia_process2.html

***if its possible to have a version that reads a value in clipboard, that would even be better.

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts here is a solution:

Script(SAPLSLVC.0500.txt):

```
inputfield (2,35)  "inv" (2,45) size=10 name="V_inv" 
pushbutton (toolbar)  "script" "/OVF03" process="startvf03.txt"
using INV = [V_inv] ' need this when opening new screen
```

InputScript (startvf03.txt):

```
parameter INV
Screen SAPMV60A.0101    'this is the VF03 screen
SET F[VBRK-VBELN] "&U[INV]"    'pass invoice # parameter
ApplyGuiScript "C:\guiXT\scripts\VF03INV.vbs"
```

VBScript (VF03INV.vbs):

```
inv = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBRK-VBELN").text
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[11]").Select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[37]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "pdf!"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'with some little extra here on how to save a pdf in SAP

'get new strings for locations (specific to my situation)
abc = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlHTML/shellcont/shell").Browserhandle.locationURL
beg = instr(abc,"C:")
cde =  mid(abc,beg,9999)
dest = "C:\111\invoices\" & inv & ".pdf"

'changing from temp to a specific folder
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.copyfile cde, dest

'close the open file
session.findById("wnd[1]").close
session.findById("wnd[0]").close
Set fso = nothing
```

*the several `If Not IsObject(application) Then` you usually see were not necessary, but doesn't hurt to have them.

I hope this helps everyone learn Guixt

Answer (score 0):

Within the VB script with the parameter "template" can you address a GuiXT variable as follows.

for example:

```
msgbox "&V[V_inv]"
```

Comment: Thanks Scriptman! I was able to get to where I wanted, which is to pass the variable from SAP to a script. It didnt worked like a charm however, the script is not running flawlessly as it used to.  First, I can't make it run in other sessions. Following code would still make it open in the same window(Set session    = connection.Children(2) ) . Second, I get at the end of the script, "cannot find by ID, although the script ran as it should. Anything you could do about that. I can put my script here if needed. thx.

Comment: OGERWOLF, Thanks for the very intelligent solution! I learned something again today. The following commands are necessary only when starting a VB script with the GuiXT command "start":                  Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = application.Children(0)
set session = application.ActiveSession                                                                           With the command "ApplyGuiScript" these are actually unnecessary. Thanks again!